# Is the following inequality true for the norm of Moore-Penrose pseudoinverses?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, inequalities, matrix-analysis

Let $L$ be a real, positive semi-definite, symmetric, square matrix, with pseudoinverse $L^{+}$. It can be shown for the operator norms $||.||_{op}$ that: if $L$ is invertible and $||I - L||_{op} < 1$, and hence $L^{+}=L^{-1},$ then $||L^{-1}||_{op}\leq \frac{1}{1- ||I - L||_{op}}$: write $L^{-1}= (I-(I-L))^{-1},$ expand the geometric series (using $||I - L||_{op} < 1$) as $\Sigma_{r=1}^{\infty} (I-L)^{r},$, and then take the norm inside the summation.

I was wondering, whether I could have in general, assuming $||I - L||_{op} < 1,$ the following inequality: $||L^{+}||_{op}\leq \frac{1}{1- ||I - L||_{op}}$? Using the limit definition of Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse, $L^{+}:=lim_{\delta\to 0} L (L^2+\delta I)^{-1}$, further assuming $||I - L^2||_{op} < 1,$ and using the inequality for (regular) inverse, I could only get: $||L^{-1}||_{op}\leq \frac{||L||}{1- ||I - L^2||_{op}}$. If the proposed inequality indeed holds, then could you show me the steps how to obtain it? Thanks!

Comment: The LHS is always nonnegative, and the RHS is negative whenever $\|I-L\| > 1$.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni but I'm not considering the case where $||I-L|| > 1,$ I'm only considering the case when $||I-L|| < 1,$ which allows us to take the geometric series expansion mentioned in my question.

Comment: If $\|I-L\|<1$, $L$ is automatically  invertible, right?

Comment: @FedorPetrov I wonder why? Could you explain?

Here's a counter example: take $s > 0$. Take $L:={e^{-\frac{1}{s}} 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1\\
   -1 & 1
  \end{bmatrix} }$.

Then $||I-L||_{\infty}= 1- e^{-\frac{1}{s}} < 1$. Hence by norm equivalence, $||I-L||_{op}< 1$ as well. But $L$ is invertible.

Comment: If $L$ is not invertible, then $Lx=0$ for some non-zero vector $x$, hence $\|(I-L)x\|=\|x\|$, $\|(I-L)x\|_{op}\geqslant 1$. Alternatively, you may denote $I-L=K$ and write $L^{-1}=(I-K)^{-1}=I+K+K^2+\dots$, the series converges if $\|K\|_{op}<1$. What do you call 'norm equivalence' contains some forgotten multiplicative constant, I guess.

Comment: @FedorPetrov You're very correct. May be I should change the norm of my question to a different norm, like Frobenius norm, with necessary adjustments, and re-ask it. Thanks!